# How to run python flask in multiprocessing without waiting another process closed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I run another gtk window to show my application, in the same time I want to run Flask.run(host:'0.0.0.0'). Flask still processing when I close my gtk.window that run my app. Can anybody help?

here is the code :

```
import multiprocessing
import opx
import app

def worker(file):
    if file == 'opx':
    opx.main()
    else :
    app.apx.run(host='0.0.0.0') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ["opx","app.py"]
    for i in files:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker(i))
        p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Why `multiprocessing`, Have you considered deploy it on `tornado` or `gevent` ?

Comment: Hai Frank, thank you for your respond. I already try it on tornado but I still stuck with it. Can you give me an example? I'm new of python...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several combinations here:

```
from flask import Flask
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
    http_server.listen(8000)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

[Flask with Gevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486682/flask-with-gevent-multicore)

[Flask with Tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563922/how-to-run-flask-app-with-tornado)

You should do more research before asked question. (Because of repeated problems can lead to confusion in the community)

Comment: Don't how to say it... Thank you so much Frank... it running perfect now...

Comment: I found that it perfect with subprocess

Comment: If I add a print statement as the last line, it never gets printed. i.e. flask is being run in blocking mode. Isn't the question how to make it run in non-blocking mode?